# Alternate definition on bounded variation

Tags: bounded-variation

If $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ the $g$ is of bounded variation iff 
$$TV(g,[a,b])=\sup\sum_{i=1}^n |g(t_i)-g(t_{i-1})|<\infty$$
where the supremum is taken over all partitions $a=t_0<t_1<\dots<t_n=b$

**Question**. If $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is of bounded variation, is it true that
$$TV(g,[a,b])=\sup\sum_{i=1}^m |g(b_i)-g(a_i)|$$
where the supremum is taken over all possible finite collection $\{[a_i,b_i]:i=1,\dots,m\}$
of nonoverlapping subintervals in $[a,b]$? I need some help on this. Thanks.

Comment: They end up being the same. Assuming that $[a,b],[b,c]$ are considered non-overlapping...

Comment: @copper.hat thanks. If its okay, can you please give me some tips on how to prove it?

Comment: Is that what you mean by non-overlapping - that the interiors do not intersect?

Comment: yes, those collection are partial partitions of $[a,b]$.

Comment: Do you consider $[a,b]$ and $[b,c]$ to be overlapping or non-overlapping?

Comment: non-overlapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(I_1,...,I_n)$ denote an ordered collection of subintervals on $[a,b]$ such that $\sup I_k \le \inf I_{k+1}$.

Let ${\cal P'}$ be the set of all such collections.

Let ${\cal P}$ be the set of partitions of $[a,b]$, it should be clear that ${\cal P} \subset {\cal P'}$.

Let $TV, TV_2$ be your definition and second formulation, respectively. I will drop the $[a,b]$ part of your notation as this is fixed here.

We have $TV(g) = \sup_{\pi \in {\cal P} } \sum_{I \in \pi} |g(\sup I) -g(\inf I)|$, and
$TV_2(g) = \sup_{\pi' \in {\cal P'} } \sum_{I \in \pi'} |g(\sup I) -g(\inf I)|$

Since ${\cal P} \subset {\cal P'}$, we have $TV(g) \le TV_2(g)$.

Now suppose $\pi' \in {\cal P'} \setminus {\cal P}$. It should be clear that we can add subintervals to $\pi'$ to get a partition $\pi \in {\cal P}$ such that every interval in $\pi'$ is also in $\pi$.
Furthermore,
$\sum_{I \in \pi'} |g(\sup I) -g(\inf I)| \le \sum_{I \in \pi} |g(\sup I) -g(\inf I)| \le TV(g)$.
Consequently, we have $TV_2(g) \le TV(g)$ and so they are equal.

**Note**: It is not hard to see that if the subintervals are **strictly** non overlapping (that is, empty intersection), then this is not true. Take
$g = 1_{\{{1\over 2}\}}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Then
$TV(g) = 2$, but $TV_2(g) = 1$.

Comment: @cooper.hat Many thanks to your answer sir.